Highcharts Vue3 don't render graph on first load
I have some Highcharts graphs for displaying temperatures of set of devices, creating it in v-for loop.
I get data from API (Laravel) by Axios and call request with onMounted:
onMounted(async () => {
    await getTemperatureDataForGraphs()
})

Also, I have watcher with same method (change date range). Period variable is v-model for select:
watch(period, async () =>{
    await getTemperatureDataForGraphs()
})

The problem: when I come to page, I see the graphs with options that I return from API (for example, graph title and style), but I can't see any series. The data structure is correct, because if I change date range from select, the series becomes visible. Also, if I make onMounted like this:
onMounted(async () => {
    await getTemperatureDataForGraphs()
    await getTemperatureDataForGraphs()
})

...I can see the series.
Data comes correctly from first load:

But the graph looks like:

But, when I select another date range (or call getTemperatureDataForGraphs from onMounted twice), the graphs begin display data:

Getting data:
const getTemperatureDataForGraphs = async() => {
        let response = await axios.get("/api/get_data_for_temps_graphs?period=" + period.value);
        temperatureData.value = response.data;
    }

Making graphs:
<div v-for="data in temperatureData">
                        <span class="text-gray-800 dark:text-gray-200">{{ data.bdcom_name }}</span>
                        <div class="box grow">
                            <highcharts v-if="data.options" :options="data.options" :redraw-on-update="true"></highcharts>
                        </div>
                    </div>

What could be the problem?
I tried use v-if, make data with load() property on graph - nothing helps.
UPD:
I find the problem (thanks to @DominikChudy for giving template).
The series data must look like: {[ data: ... ]}, but I retured this like { data } (without [])
I add object on Laravel side:
$data[] = (object)[ ... ]

And make series structure like this:
'series' => [[
               'name' => $b->bdcom_name,
               'data' => $temp,
            ]]

Also, I return data with json:
return response()->json($data);

And after this changes my graphs correctly render on first load.

Could you please reproduce this problem in an online editor I could work on? You can use this demo as a basic template: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/silly-bhaskara-k64zry?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue
